# After updating to chromedriver 76 I'm getting the exception "disconnected: received Inspector.detached event" in selenium

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, eclipse, selenium

OS: Windows 7
Chrome Version: 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)
I've updated chromedrive to support chrome version 76. Later on i'm getting "disconnected: received Inspector.detached event" error while running selenium code in eclipse. The browser is invoked and the url is fetched. Later it is getting disconnected.

Can anybody help me find a solution?

Comment: This would be better suited to our sister site [so].

Answer (score -1):

Check if Chrome->Developer Tools are enabled.